# How can I use v-model to assign values in 2D array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to assign values to 2D array by using `v-model`.

Here's my array of objects **:**

```js
[
  {
    first_attribute_value: 'red',
    second_attribute_value: 'meduim',
    third_attribute_value: 'cotton',
    quantity: [
      { location_id: 32, quantity: '' },
      { location_id: 31, quantity: '' },
      { location_id: 30, quantity: '' },
      { location_id: 1, quantity: '' },
    ],
  },
  {
    first_attribute_value: 'red',
    second_attribute_value: 'meduim',
    third_attribute_value: 'leather',
    quantity: [
      { location_id: 32, quantity: '' },
      { location_id: 31, quantity: '' },
      { location_id: 30, quantity: '' },
      { location_id: 1, quantity: '' },
    ],
  },
],
```

```js
and thats my function that return the testvar array :

 setVariancesJSON(){
           this.firstattrs.forEach(first=>{
             if(this.secondattrs.length && this.thirdattrs.length){
            this.secondattrs.forEach(second=>{
            this.thirdattrs.forEach(third=>{
            this.testvar.push({
            first_attribute: this.attrnames[0],
            first_attribute_value: first,
            second_attribute: this.attrnames[1],
            second_attribute_value: second,
            third_attribute: this.attrnames[2],
            third_attribute_value: third,
            quantity:this.freeProductQuantity
                     })
                 })
             })
             }
             else if(this.secondattrs.length && !this.thirdattrs.length){
                 this.secondattrs.forEach(second=>{
                     this.testvar.push({
            first_attribute: this.attrnames[0],
            first_attribute_value: first,
            second_attribute: this.attrnames[1],
            second_attribute_value: second,
            third_attribute: null,
            third_attribute_value:null,
            quantity:this.freeProductQuantity
                     })
                 })
             }
             else{
                   this.testvar.push({
            first_attribute: this.attrnames[0],
            first_attribute_value: first,
            second_attribute:null,
            second_attribute_value: null,
            third_attribute: null,
            third_attribute_value:null,
            quantity:this.freeProductQuantity
                     })
             }

         })
     }
```

I wanted to assign values to `quantity` attribute in each `quantity` array

I tried this **:**

```html
<tr v-for="(attr,index) in testvar " :key="index">
  <td class="col-2 text-center" v-for="(warehouse,index2) in warehouses" :key="index2">
    <input v-model="testvar[index].quantity[index2].quantity">
  </td>
</tr>
```

But it reflects the same numbers in all input fields for each column, like it always reads `"[index]"` with the same value in each iteration.

Comment: Formatted your question quite a bit.

Comment: `v-model` is some sugar syntax replacing `:value` and `@input`. You should probably try to be explicit and to do it _manually_ with a method taking into account every index of each loop.

Comment: What is `warehouses` ?

Comment: @MonaShazly I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at following snippet (`index2` was wrong):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      testvar: [{"first_attribute_value": "red", "second_attribute_value": "meduim", "third_attribute_value": "cotton", "quantity": [{"location_id": 32, "quantity": "5" }, {"location_id": 31, "quantity": ""}, {"location_id": 30, "quantity": ""}, {"location_id": 1, "quantity": ""}]}, {"first_attribute_value": "red", "second_attribute_value": "meduim", "third_attribute_value": "leather", "quantity": [{"location_id": 32, "quantity": ""}, {"location_id": 31, "quantity": "7"}, {"location_id": 30, "quantity": ""}, {"location_id": 1, "quantity": ""}]}]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(attr, index) in testvar " :key="index"> 
      <td class="col-2 text-center" v-for="(warehouse, index2) in attr.quantity" :key="index2"> 
        {{ warehouse.location_id }}
        <input v-model="testvar[index].quantity[index2].quantity"> 
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>{{ testvar }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I did but im having the same issue, each input reflects number to other inputs

Comment: @Mona Shazly hey, did you try snippet, you can see there what input are reflected

Comment: yeah it works well , but i have no clue why it's not working with me , anyway thank you

Comment: @MonaShazly depends where is your array of objects.

Comment: what do u mean @kissu

Comment: @MonaShazly where is your array of objects with `first_attribute_value: 'red', etc...`?

Comment: @kissu returned from a function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is `warehouses`. You should perform second iteration on quantity array inside each object of `testvar`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testVar: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      this.testVar.push({
          first_attribute_value: 'red',
          second_attribute_value: 'meduim',
          third_attribute_value: 'cotton',
          quantity: [
            { location_id: 32, quantity: '' },
            { location_id: 31, quantity: '' },
            { location_id: 30, quantity: '' },
            { location_id: 1, quantity: '' },
          ],
        },
        {
          first_attribute_value: 'red',
          second_attribute_value: 'meduim',
          third_attribute_value: 'leather',
          quantity: [
            { location_id: 32, quantity: '' },
            { location_id: 31, quantity: '' },
            { location_id: 30, quantity: '' },
            { location_id: 1, quantity: '' },
          ],
        }) 
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="getData()">Get Data</button>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(attr,index) in testVar" :key="index">
      <td class="col-2 text-center" v-for="(warehouse,index2) in attr.quantity" :key="index2">
        <input v-model="testVar[index].quantity[index2].quantity">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is my array of objects isn't in data() , it is returned from a function so this way doesn't work with me , but when i put dummy data in data() scope it works fine

Comment: In that case you can assign an empty array in your data object and then in mounted you can assign the data getting from the function in that variable. I updated the answer as per your comment.

Comment: but i create the array when I click a specific button :/

Comment: yes you can achieve that in any way. As per this comment, instead of calling `getData()` on mounted. you can call it on button click. It is simple

Comment: yes and this what makes it doesn't work :) @Rohit ,, it works only when i put array statically in data()

Comment: I again updated my answer as per your latest comment and it is working like a champ

Comment: I don't know what you are not understanding. I think first you have to go through the vuejs documentation to learn how it works. I already added the solution as per your requirement.

Comment: i know how vuejs works you just don't understand my question :) , anyway thank U !